# How to change a constant expression to a literal number during preprocessing? (use gcc)

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming

The code like:

```
void f1(){
    /* ... */
}

void f2(){
    /* ... */
}

int main()
{
    const int n=2;
    USE(f, n)();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope it can call f2().

if we just define like:

```
#define PASTE(a,b) a##b
#define USE(a,b) PASTE(a,b)
```

it will call fn(). So we should define a new macro to change n to 2, like:

```
#define PASTE(a,b) a##b
#define CHANGE_constexpr_TO_literal(n)  // I don't know how to define
#define USE(a,b) PASTE(a,CHANGE_constexpr_TO_literal(b))
```

then the expansion of *CHANGE_constexpr_TO_literal(n)* will be *2* .

Is it possible to define the macro to force a **constexpr** *n* to be **literal** *n*? How to define it if possible?

Note:

- I use GCC compiler, so gnu c extensions are available.
- Only during preprocessing. I know how to do while during compilation. But it doesn't have to be a macro.
- Furthermore, is it possible to change a string constant expression to a literal string? And how to do it?

Comment: what is "string constant expression" ?

Comment: Maybe I use wrong terminology. I mean the string that can be determined by code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be done. Preprocessor operates only on tokens before any C grammar rules are applied. Therefore `const int n` is *not* even parsed when `USE` macro is about to be expanded.

The workaround would be defining `USE()` as a chain of conditional operator selecting an desired function pointer depending on `n`.

```
#define USE(f, n) (    \
   (n == 0) ? f ## 0 : \
   (n == 1) ? f ## 1 : \
   (n == 2) ? f ## 2 : \
   NULL)
```

The advantage of this approach is that if `n` is a constant expression then the value of `USE()` is a constant expression as well.

BTW. In standard C the `const int n = 2;` **does not** make `n` a constant expression. Use either a macro or enum:

```
#define n 2
```

or

```
enum { n = 2 };
```

Comment: Thank you. I know this method with number or string. But I don't know how about preprocessing before.

Comment: @fusztal, it's difficult to control preprocessor with anything other than a single token. Even `1+1` is perceived by preporcessor as sequence of (`1`,`+`,`1`) tokens. Not as `2`. There are some trick to do some basic computation in macros but they tend to be complex. See http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic

Comment: Please note however that this leads to run-time evaluation with branches. Not an ideal solution in any scenario. Yet another better alternative might be an array of function pointers with `n` as index.

Comment: @Lundin Doesn't the compiler optimize for it? After all this is a constant.

Comment: @fusztal It probably does indeed, but it's still a run-time decision (that the compiler managed to optimize out). Make `const int n` a parameter of a function with external linkage and it won't be able to optimize it, for example.

Comment: @tstanisl I considered using _Generic too but I don't think you can have a compound literal VLA?

Comment: @Lundin, there is some hope that `constexpr` will be added to C. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2851.pdf. It should solve the issue of true const on C's 50th aniversary

Comment: @Lundin, yes, that is why I've removed the update immediatelly

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why we still use `#define` constants and not type safe `const` variables is that the former can be used in pre-processor macros. A variable in C is never a compile-time constant and its value can't be accessed by the pre-processor.

So the fix is to change the `const` variable to a `#define` macro, or it can't be done:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1(void){
    puts(__func__);
}

void f2(void){
    puts(__func__);
}

#define PASTE(f,n) f##n
#define USE(f,n) PASTE(f,n)

#define n 2

int main (void)
{
    USE(f,n)();  // this is btw a horrible poor way of writing C code
    return 0;
}
```

---

A saner and more readable solution would be a function pointer table:

```
typedef void func_t (void);

static func_t* const f[] = { f0, f1, f2 };
...
f[n]();
```